# DBContext in MVC 5 - Why are my RemoveRange and AddRange methods not updating the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to delete a list of "IncidentDescriptions" and then add in any new ones from the form.  I have used the debugging tools to confirm that there are valid objects with values in the parameters for the `RemoveRange` and `AddRange` methods.

```
private Accident_Reporting_Entities DB = new Accident_Reporting_Entities(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Facility"].ToString());

List<IncidentDescription> descriptionsToRemove = DB.IncidentDescriptions.Where(d => d.AccidentHeaderId == supervisor.AccidentHeaderId).ToList();
var descList = new List<IncidentDescription>();
for (var x = 0; x < supervisor.IncidentDescriptions.Count; x++) {
    var desc = new IncidentDescription(); 
    desc.AccidentHeaderId = supervisor.AccidentHeaderId;
    desc.Username = DescriptionUser[x] ?? "N/A";
    desc.Position = DescriptionPosition[x] ?? "N/A";
    descList.Add(desc);
}
DB.IncidentDescriptions.RemoveRange(descriptionsToRemove);
DB.IncidentDescriptions.AddRange(descList);
DB.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not functioning"? Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: Worth noting that you are not creating new items to add since you create the object outside the for loop and just keep updating the same item again and again.

Comment: @DavidG I clarified the title with an edit.  There is no error, the rows in the database just never get updated and the application continues as normal after the SaveChanges method.

Comment: David is right.  You should move your desc object into the loop, so for every loop, it creates a new object.  EF thinks it's the same object over and over with changed properties.

Comment: @JasonRoner I have moved the object into the loop, but I'm still having the same issues

Comment: @PeterSmith how can I fetch ``IncidentDescriptions``?  Isn't that happening with the line ``DB.IncidentDescriptions.AddRange(descList);``?

Comment: I recommend you wrap SaveChanges around a try/catch.  It may seem that you are not getting an error from EF, but to be on the safe side, you could see if it does catch an error this way

Comment: @JasonRoner I actually do have it in a try/catch (although I didn't include it in this questions code) and I even place a breakpoint on the catch, but it never gets called.

Comment: It wouldn't  hurt to shorten things a little and instead of descList.Add() in the end of the loop, just put DB.IncidentDescriptions.Add(desc).  Comment out the AddRange() before SaveChanges.   Also, I'd try putting another SaveChanges right after RemoveRange.  I know you want to save trips to the DB, but it's kind of messy when you are doing too many things with one stone.  edit:  SaveChanges right after the loop, and then another after the RemoveRange

Comment: What is the PK of your `IncidentDescription` entity? If it is `AccidentHeaderId` then you have to update your entities, not delete and insert them.